# Searchable database of popular smart contracts?

Tags: repositories

Is there a searchable database of smart contract somewhere?  I'm starting to run across a lot of useful open source smart contracts, from entities like Open Zeppelin, others found in a whole bunch of articles on Medium,  smart contract GitHub repos I stumble across, etc. and I am now officially in a state of "fear of missing out (FOMO)" when I start coding a new smart contract, because there might be something better and safer out there already.

Given that mistakes in a smart contract live forever on the blockchain and can cost users money if there are bugs, I'm more aggressive than usual about finding well-tested existing code before writing something myself.